# How to make a UICollectionViewCell reorderable?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I need to be able to long press a cell and drag it to a new position inside the same collection view.

Here's my example in Android version:

[image]

Comment: look this example  https://github.com/pgpt10/DragAndDrop-CollectionView

Comment: You can use Swift's `UICollectionView` to achieve this.

Comment: apple document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_collection_views

Answer (score 2):

**Reordering Items in collectionview**

```
func collectionView(UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt: IndexPath)
```

Asks your data source object whether the specified item can be moved to another location in the collection view.

```
func collectionView(UICollectionView, moveItemAt: IndexPath, to: IndexPath)
```

Tells your data source object to move the specified item to its new location.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource

---

**Sample code:**

**UICollectionViewDelegate**

We will start by using two delegate methods from the **UICollectionViewDelegate** protocol.

Enable the use of moving items in the `UICollectionView` by calling `canMoveItemAt` delegate method. Passing true will enable this feature.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
   return true
}
```

Next, we will implement the `moveItemAt` delegate method where you will intercept the starting index and the ending index of the both items that are switching places.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
   print(“Starting Index: \(sourceIndexPath.item)”)
   print(“Ending Index: \(destinationIndexPath.item)”)
}
```

For a better control of the gestures in the UICollectionView we will implement a UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

```
fileprivate var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
    reorderCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}


@objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch(gesture.state) {

    case .began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = reorderCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: reorderCollectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        reorderCollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case .changed:
        reorderCollectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case .ended:
        reorderCollectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        reorderCollectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

Note that these interactive functions work for iOS 9 and above.

Source Link: https://theappspace.com/swift-reorder-cells-uicollectionview-using-drag-drop/